Create a screen in the flet with all the available bluetooth devices
i'm learning to use flet together with bluetooth and i'm trying to connect it to an ESP-32, but i can't make a screen that shows buttons with the names of all the available bluetooth devices so that i can click on them and when i click on them make the connection between the flet application and the Arduino.
Can you help me?
#import bluetooth.btcommon
import flet as ft
import bluetooth

def main(page:ft.page):

    def parear(e):
        print(nome[botao.data])

        def ligarLed(e):
            dado = "1"
            sock.send(dado)
            print("dado 1 enviado")
        pass
        def desligarLed(e):
            dado = "2"
            sock.send(dado)
            print("dado 2 enviado")
        pass
        def desconectarBT(e):
            sock.close()
            page.add(
                page.clean(),
                ft.Text("Desconectado.")
                )
        pass

        if nome[botao.data] == 'ESP-32':
            print("entrou no esp32")
            print(nome[botao.data])
            print(endereco[botao.data])
            sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM) #BluetoothSocket é com um tipo de "variavel" e está definindo sock como um socket
            mac = endereco[botao.data]
            porta = 1

            try:
                b1 = ft.ElevatedButton("Ligar LED",on_click = ligarLed)
                b2 = ft.ElevatedButton("Desligar LED",on_click = desligarLed)
                b3 = ft.ElevatedButton("Desconectar",on_click = desconectarBT)
                sock.connect((mac,porta))
                page.clean()
                page.add(
                        ft.Text(f"O dispositivo {nome[botao.data]} foi conectado!"),
                        b1,
                        b2,
                        b3
                        )
                page.update()
                
            except bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError as e:
                page.clean()
                page.add(ft.Text("Não foi possivel se conectar com o dispositivo"))
                sock.close()
                page.update()
        pass
    
    dispostivos_proximos = bluetooth.discover_devices(lookup_names=True)#procurar os dispositivos bluetooth
    endereco = [item[0] for item in dispostivos_proximos]#Ter todos os valores de endereço numa lista
    nome = [item[1] for item in dispostivos_proximos]#Todos os nomes dos dispositivos numa lista

    page.add(ft.Text("DISPOSITIVOS BLUETOOTH DISPONIVEIS"))#Label simples

    for i in range(0,len(dispostivos_proximos)):
        botao = ft.ElevatedButton(nome[i],on_click=parear,data=i)
        page.add(
            botao
        )
    page.update()

ft.app(target = main) #Para transformar a aplicação é web basta adicionar ,view = ft.WEB_BROWSER


don't put one function inside another function because it makes code unreadable.
